# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to run a Java application which makes a https call to a server, but keep getting the following SSL error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.write(HttpConnection.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.write(HttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.print(HttpConnection.java:1032)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequestLine(HttpMethodBase.java:2077)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1918)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
        ...
        ...
        ...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
```

I read on other posts that I need to add the certificate in lib/security/cacerts. So I downloaded the certificate file from the server using Firefox, and ran the following command:

```
sudo keytool -import -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias samplecert-root -trustcacerts -file VeriSignClass3SecureServerCA.crt 
Certificate was added to keystore
```

However, I still keep getting the error. What is the problem? Did I add the certificate properly to the keystore?

Comment: Please paste your relevant `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` output into the question. Have you read the [oracle example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)?

Comment: It's probably asking for a certificate that you aren't sending. Can you run your client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and post the output here?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause of the error was that I was using a certificate as a client certificate that was a server-only certificate.